# ST_WITHIN or ST_CONTAINS with POLYGON across IDL or Greenwich

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial

I'm having a question regarding spatial functions with MySQL 8.0.13 server.
I try to determine if a polygon contains a point, using ST_Contains function.
In my tests, both spherical objects (polygon and point) are defined with the SGID 4326 (WGS84 projection).

- Northeastern quarter of the earth polygon:

  SELECT (ST_Contains(
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((0 0,0 180,90 180,90 0,0 0))',4326),
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(10 10)',4326 )
  ))

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

- Polygon in France croosing the Greenwich meridian

  SELECT (ST_Contains(
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((41 -6,41 10.5,51.5 10.5,51.5 -6,41 -6))',4326),
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(45 2)',4326 )
  ))

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

```
SELECT (ST_Contains(
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((41 -6,41 10.5,51.5 10.5,51.5 -6,41 -6))',4326),
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(45 -2)',4326 )
))
```

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

- Polygon in Pacific Ocean crossing the International Date Line:

  SELECT (ST_Contains(
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-45 100,-45 -100,45 -100, 45 100, -45 100))',4326),
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 179)',4326 )
  ))

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

```
SELECT (ST_Contains(
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-45 100,-45 -100,45 -100, 45 100, -45 100))',4326),
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 -179)',4326 )
))
```

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

- World clockwise: SW,SE,NE,NW,SW

  SELECT (ST_Contains(
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-90 -180,-90 180,90 180,90 -180,-90 -180))',4326),
      ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 0)',4326 )
  ))

... returns 0. KO, the point is not detected as part of the polygon.

```
SELECT (ST_Contains(
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-90 -180,-90 180,90 180,90 -180,-90 -180))',0),
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 0)',0)
))
```

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

```
SELECT (ST_Contains(
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-89.99 -180,-89.99 180,89.99 180,89.99 -180,-89.99 -180))',0),
    ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 0)',0)
))
```

... returns 1: OK, the point is contained by the polygon.

I think POLYGON((-90 -180,-90 180,90 180,90 -180,-90 -180)) is not relevant using spatial WGS84 coordinates; all points used into this polygon are north|south poles!
When using a flat projection (SGID 0), it works well.
I also tried to reduce latitudes to avoid using poles; with 89.99° instead of 90°, it works too.

My question is then, is there a workaround/other solutioin to define a full earth 'polygon' (using 90° latitudes) so I can use a generic SQL query that works on every cases.

Christophe

Comment: Oups; I forgot to replace the SRID in the last command (using 89.99°).
   SELECT (ST_Contains(
        ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-89.99 -180,-89.99 180,89.99 180,89.99 -180,-89.99 -180))',4326),
     ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(0 0)',4326)
    ))
... returns 0. KO, the point is not detected as part of the polygon.

Comment: "it works well. I also tried to reduce latitudes to avoid using poles; with 89.99° instead of 90°, it works too." "My question is then, is there a workaround/other solutioin to define a full earth 'polygon' (using 90° latitudes)" For what kind of application do you need this?

Comment: Another test, add points when crossing Equator, Greenwich meridian and the IDL meridian:

    SELECT (ST_Contains(
        ST_GeomFromText( 'POLYGON((-90 -180,-90 0,-90 180,0 180,90 180,90 0, 90 -180,0 -180,-90 -180))',4326),
     ST_GeomFromText( 'POINT(1 1)',4326)
    ))

This time, MySQL returns 1. But is it a valid workaround ?

Comment: @Raymond Nijland A weatherforecast service app. I have setup a list of GRIB models with boundaries defined by polygons in a MySQL table; then I'm looking for all available GRIB models that fit my locations.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 isn't that old i believe it was released somewhere around April this year. MySQL 8.0 is the first MySQL database which implements  Spatial Reference Systems (SRS) calculations it might still contain a  "bug or two" for some grids.. I advice you to post this on the MySQL dev forums..

Comment: Just curious to know, when you want to cover who earth, then why search for contain at all? I mean whatever database you have with coordinates, you eventually have to pick all record only? Though your question is good for learning purpose but I don't see you need it in real?

Comment: Some models covers the whole world, some only a part of it and some are across the IDL. My services gets as input the BBOX, it should work whatever the BBOX is... The whole world is a specific test case; but you're right in case of such BBOX, we could get ALL points ^^